# Using Luhn's module I am having a problem with IF statements

Tags: python, if-statement, input, module, luhn

```
import luhn
from luhn import *

#BIN Must Be 6-Digits Long.
def gen():
  BIN = input("Enter A BIN Number: ")
  output = []
  for number in BIN:
    output.append(number)
  output = [int(num) for num in output]
  return (output)
BIN = gen()
if BIN <6 and len(BIN) is not 8:
    print('Invalid BIN!')
else:
    print('BIN Added To Directory!')


gen()
```

Specifically in the 'if' part my intention is that the 'BIN' which should be an integer is less than or greater than 6 print 'invalid' else print 'added to directory'.  In addition, overall what Im looking for is if the BIN is not 6 digits long or greater than 6 digits long print 'error'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you expect `BIN` to be a number and a list at the same time. So, in the `if` condition you are checking whether `BIN` is a **number** less than 6 and at the same time checking the **length** of it.

I figured you might want to perform both operations on the same line. So, here is what I suggest; there is no need to change the type of `BIN`. It's better to use it as a `str` just like so:

```
BIN = input("Enter A BIN Number: ")
if eval(BIN) <6 and len(BIN) != 8:
    print('Invalid BIN!')
else:
    print('BIN Added To Directory!')
```

Comment: So basically I'm trying to check digit ``len()`` would I have to convert the input or BIN into a list and then how would I go about counting each digit?

Comment: This is the error I get: ``if eval(BIN) <6 and len(BIN) != 8:
NameError: name 'BIN' is not defined``

Comment: If you want to check the number of digits in your number, then you don't need to convert it to a list. You can use `len(BIN)` as it it and it will return the number of digits. For example, `len("1234")=4`

Comment: As you can see, before the `If` statement, there is a line where it inputs BIN from the user.

Comment: Solution was found: ``import luhn
from luhn import *

def check():
    BIN = input('Enter BIN Number: ')
    if len(BIN) <6:
        print('Invalid BIN!')
    else:
        print('BIN Added To Directory!')

while True:
    check()``

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :)